# load data into Google Cloud SQL from Google Sheets

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I've having issues with loading the "Dates" column into SQL Cloud from Google sheets via Google apps script & JDBC. Not sure how I need to address the "Dates" column properly:

```
function writeManyRecords() {


  var newWs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('99zuFo9wW9C6Uzw82VQ1v1ZGNuedzbqUa2_tVby7kkcccc');


  var sheet3 = newWs.getSheetByName('sheet4');

  var sheet3DataRange = sheet3.getDataRange();
  var sheet3DataRangeValues = sheet3DataRange.getValues();

  var AvalsColumn = sheet3.getLastColumn();
  var AvalsRow = sheet3.getLastRow();

  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);

  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO SalesData7 '
    + '(Store,Dates,Counts,Units,Sales) values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
  for (var i = 1; i < AvalsRow; i++) {
    stmt.setString(1,sheet3DataRangeValues[i][0]);
    stmt.setDate(2,sheet3DataRangeValues[i][1]);
    stmt.setInt(3, sheet3DataRangeValues[i][2]);
    stmt.setInt(4, sheet3DataRangeValues[i][3]);
    stmt.setInt(5, sheet3DataRangeValues[i][4]);
    stmt.addBatch();
  }

  var batch = stmt.executeBatch();

  conn.commit();
  conn.close();
```

Comment: what specific problem are you having and what's the expected outcome. Are you having fetching the dates or writing the dates into Google Cloud SQL?

Comment: having issues with writing into Google Cloud SQL, but just for "Dates".